# How to get location of gem using bundler or Rails from within Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I need to get the current working directory of a gem from within a Rails application.

I currently use

```
`bundle show foo`.strip
```

This works great in my environment, but:

- it's slow because it requires loading a shell
- it will probably break when somebody tries to run the app on Windows or on JRuby or when their $PATH points at a different ruby than the one used to start the app

So I'd like a way to do this without invoking a subshell.

The RDOC for Bundler hasn't been helpful.   You used to be able to get this sort of information from Rails itself in Rails 2, but it appears that Rails 3 lets Bundler handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a gem is in your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock, its path appears in the `$LOAD_PATH` global variable. You can take advantage of this fact:

```
$:.grep(/activerecord/).first
```

`$:` is the same as `$LOAD_PATH`. You can use either.

**Another approach:**

```
Bundler.load.specs.find{|s| s.name == 'activerecord' }.try(:full_gem_path)
```

Comment: It's not pretty, but that basic idea should work.   One problem is that many gems have "activerecord" somewhere in their name, so I need an exact match.   In my case, active record shows up as .../gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib.   Can I count on the name starting with / and ending with -?   Is a backslash possible?  Is it possible for the gem to be unversioned?   I'm now using `/[\/\\]activerecord[\/\\-]/`.   Can you think of any other possible border characters?

Comment: @BryanLarsen I've updated my answer. See **Another approach**. Based on gem's name.

Comment: Is "another approach" supposed to be a link?

Comment: @BryanLarsen As I said, I updated my answer with "Another approach" section. The code there returns a path as a `String`, or `nil` if there's no gem with the specified name.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.   I'm not sure why I didn't the first time.   Temporary blindness, or something.   That approach does look cleaner.